# SQL Server 2008: How to fix duplicate values in one column based on other

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I have searched a lot on this and i guess i cant put it correctly for any search engine to understand. Hence requesting your help.

I am joining two tables 1) Calls and 2) Transfers

The output from calls table is Date, Name & Calls, 1 entry for each person for that date.

The output from transfers table will be date, name, transferred from, transferred to, transfers

when join these two tables using agent & date combination, call entries get duplicated which will be the case as one person will have multiple transfer from and to departments on a particular date.

I want to consider calls only once so that i can calculate transfer %

Example below:
Calls Table output:

```
Date    Agent   Calls
01/05/2016  Mark    20
```

Transfers table output:

```
Date    Agent   Trf From    Trf To  Transfers
01/05/2016  Mark    Dept A  Dept B  10
01/05/2016  Mark    Dept A  Dept C  5
01/05/2016  Mark    Dept A  Dept D  2
```

Joined Output

```
Date    Agent   Calls   Trf From    Trf To  Transfers
01/05/2016  Mark    20  Dept A  Dept B  10
01/05/2016  Mark    20  Dept A  Dept C  5
01/05/2016  Mark    20  Dept A  Dept D  2
```

Output I  need

```
Date    Agent   Calls   Trf From    Trf To  Transfers
01/05/2016  Mark    20  Dept A  Dept B  10
01/05/2016  Mark    0   Dept A  Dept C  5
01/05/2016  Mark    0   Dept A  Dept D  2
```

Comment: Hi Sanmukh, welcome to SO. If you want us to help, you must show effort solving your problem: what did you try, why didn't it work... Otherwise we might think you want us to do your work. Would we get your pay then?

Comment: I am not a pro on SQL and trying to learn on my own. I can get the output on excel by using the formulas mentioned below : =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1) =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A3=A3)*($B$2:$B3=B3))>1,0,1)

Comment: The excel becomes much heavier and was thinking if i can get to know about a SQL function that i am not aware of to fix this. I just need a hint and i will try and crack the logic on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: `Partition by` duplicated fields to get first row using `row_number()`
Implementation:

```
select c.Date, c.Agent, 
    case when row_number() over (partition by c.Date, c.Agent 
            order by t.[Trf From], t.[Trf To]) = 1 then c.Calls else 0 end as Calls, 
    t.[Trf From], t.[Trf To], t.Transfers
from Calls c
inner join Transfers t
on c.Date = t.Date and c.Agent = t.Agent
order by c.Date, c.Agent, t.[Trf From], t.[Trf To];
```